# Percona tool pt-table-checksum does not return results

Tags: mariadb, percona

I have a MariaDB (10.4.14) Master-Slave configuration and I want to use Percona pt-table-checksum. I have installed Percona Toolkit in the Master host, which includes pt-table-checksum 3.2.1.
I have created a user to run pt-table-checksum and granted his privileges:

```
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE,PROCESS,SUPER, SELECT ON *.* TO `checksum_user`@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'checksum_password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON percona.* TO `checksum_user`@'%';
```

However, when I try to run the tool, I always get the following error:

```
pt-table-checksum --replicate=percona.checksums --ignore-databases mysql --no-check-binlog-format h=localhost, u=checksum_user, p=checksum_password
Usage: pt-table-checksum [OPTIONS] [DSN]

Errors in command-line arguments:
  * More than one host specified; only one allowed
```

Instead of using the DSN, I have also tried the options `--host`,`--user` and `--password`, but the results are the same.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change: `--no-check-binlog-format` by `--nocheck-binlog-format`, `h=localhost` by `-h localhost`, `u=checksum_user` by `-u checksum_user` and `p=checksum_password` by `-pchecksum_password`.

Comment: The answer was really close. I ran: `pt-table-checksum --replicate=percona.checksums --ignore-databases mysql --no-check-binlog-format --host localhost --user checksum_user --password checksum_password` and there it was! Thank you!